# Rav Chaim Palagi on what is more important: writing seforim or giving shiurim

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, torah-writing

I heard in an [interview with Rabbi Daniel Glatstein and ArtScroll](https://youtu.be/8JpZDVBGZhc?t=2387) (min. 39:47) that [Rav Chaim Palagi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim_Palachi#Works) wrote on the importance of writing seforim.

Rav Chaim Palagi is said to have explained that writing seforim is more important, since then you can share Torah with the world instead of the limited people listening to your shiur (that was applicable back then, now we have the internet :)). This seems also to be the explanation Rav Moshe Feinstein gives somewhere in Dibros Moshe on Bava Kamma.

I really like this thought, but I am not familiar with his writings. **Can someone maybe point me to the location of these words of Rav Chaim Palagi**?

Comment: It has been reported in writing the Chazon Ish told exactly the same to R Chaim Kanievsky

Comment: There are several sources that stam point to the importance of writing seforim, I believe it is mentioned in Sefer Chasidim and Teshuvos HaRashbah

Comment: וְיֹתֵר מֵהֵמָּה בְּנִי הִזָּהֵר עֲשׂוֹת סְפָרִים הַרְבֵּה אֵין קֵץ (https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%91)

Comment: @mbloch nice. Rabbi Glatstein mentions that he once visited Rav Chaim Kanievsky and asked him this question.

Comment: @Dov Nice. Although I am looking for the source in Rav Palagi's works, adding these sources in would make an answer even more better :)

Comment: I can tell you the Rav Moshe source but not the Rav Chaim one :-)

Comment: @Dov What is the Rav Moshe source?

Comment: @Dov wonderful :)

Comment: It writes in the footnotes on p.139 in the Artscroll autobiography - "Reb Moshe viewed the publishing of one's Torah thoughts as a sacred obligation. In the preface to the first volume of Dibros Moshe he writes, "The benefit of publishing that which Hashem Yisborach has helped me understand [in the words of our Sages] through much toil and effort...is obvious...It seems to me that one who has the ability to publish his chiddushim and does not has not fulfilled the mitzvah of teaching Torah to others in its fullest sense...""

Comment: See here: - https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40812&st=&pgnum=2&hilite=

Comment: @Dov thank you very much! This seems to be the Dibros Moshe Rav Glatstein was talking about in that interview. Feel free to put it into an answer if you would like :) Kol HaKavod!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rav Daniel Glatstein writes this idea in his introduction to his Hebrew sefer "Maggid HaRakiah - Nissan/Pesach":

> כיודע, ישנם כמה דרכים ואופנים בהרבצת התורה לרבים, שכולם מובילים למטרה אחת - להגדיל תורה ולהאדירה. אולם כתב רבי חיים פלאג'י (זכירה לחיים שיר השירים סימן א) שיש עדיפות מיוחדת ללמד תורה לאחרים דוקא על ידי הדפסת ספרים: ונראה דהמחבר ספר ומדפיסו להוציא לאור תורתו, טפי מעלי מהדורש ברבים. כי הדורש הוא דווקא אל עירו ואל שער מקומו, אכן המוציא ספר הולך מסוף העולם ועד סופו, והוא אף כי אחרי מותו ולדורי דורות.
>
> As is known, there are many ways and paths to spread Torah to the masses. They all have the same goal - To increase the Torah and glorify it. However, Rav Chaim Palagi (Zechira LaChaim, Shir HaShirim § 1) writes that there's a specific advantage to teaching Torah to others specifically through printing books:
>
> "It appears that someone who authors books and prints them and brings to fruition the light of their Torah, is much greater than someone who expounds orally in public. For the speaker is only to his city, and the gates of his location. In contrast, someone who distributes books goes from one end of the world to the next. Furthermore, this is even after his death, for all the generations."

So the source is [Zechira LaChaim *Shir HaShirim* § 1, s.v. א"ר יודן](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=5805&st=&pgnum=297)

Comment: Wonderful @Robev. Thank you very much. If you would like to translate the original piece of Rav Chaim Palagi, I accept the answer :)